# Google Doc manipulations with .net

Tags: c#, google-docs, google-docs-api

Does anyone know, how to replace tags in a google doc with .net code.

> Hello << name >>
>   This is << my_name >>.

and replace << name >> and << my_name >> with C#.

Is there any other way to this. I know that I can use interops and office dlls for this, but then I need to have office installed on my server which is not a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably using the [GDATA API](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/), particularly with [Documents](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/overview.html) and [Spreadsheets](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/overview.html).  Here is the guide to [getting started in .NET](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#GettingStarted).

Comment: Can I also edit the documents?! It looks to me that it gives you the ability of querying docs and keywords in the doc. I don't see anything about editing the document.